# How to edit a .yml file in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny application which pulls data from various APIs and databases. All the sensitive data pertaining to credentials, usernames, passwords etc. are stored in a `config.yml` file. The code within the Shiny app calls variables within the `config.yml` file for connecting to different APIs/databases.

I have also created an administrator login for the Shiny application and want to provide access to the administrator for making changes in the `config.yml` file. The Shiny app has a separate tab called `Admin` whiich opens up when the administrator logs in. How can I open the `config.yml` file and allow edits by the administrator and save it?

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately nothing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a tab for the configuration file and using Shiny Ace as editor:

```
library(shinyAce) 

# UI

aceEditor(
          outputId = "someID",
          value = read.delim("config.yml"),
          placeholder = "Connection configuration file"
         ), 

        actionButton("save", label = "Save Configuration")

# Sever

 observeEvent(input$save, {
    write(x = input$someID, file = "config.yml")
    print("file saved")

    })
```

Then you can call to the config.yml and apply the configurations.

Comment: sounds great! Will try this out. Can the tab be password protected?

Comment: yes, with shiny server pro. However, it may be possible with some work around, but not straight forward.